# Cut part from function

Tags: functions

I try implement cutting some `ease` function.

I have one ease function `ease(x)` where x (0,1) and result (0,1).

I can not understand what the function will be above ease function. The function must repeat the form of the original function in the specified range (from, to), while its parameter must also be in the range 0-1 and the result (y0, y1) must also be in the range 0-1.

[image]

I try something like:

```
d = to - from
efrom = easing(from)
eto = easing(to)
ed = eto - efrom

f = (easing(from + X * d) - efrom) / ed
```

but something is wrong

Comment: this is more of a math question in general, but I think all answers will be useful

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your function is

```
f[x_]:= Sqrt[(x^3) ] Sin[x]; 
xmin=0;
xmax=4 Pi;
```

[image]

Let's make the BSpline,

```
bf = BSplineFunction[Table[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax,(xmax-xmin)/200}]];
max = Maximize[bf[t], {t} \[Element] Interval[{0, 1}]][[1]];
min = Minimize[bf[t], {t} \[Element] Interval[{0, 1}]][[1]];
```

The final function is

```
(bf[t] + Abs@min)/(max - min)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the function from @Rom38's answer:

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[(x^3)] Sin[x];

xmin = 0; xmax = 15;
Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

[image]

```
ymax = NMaximize[{f[x], x >= xmin && x <= xmax}, x][[1]]
 (* 53.4522 *)

ymin = NMinimize[{f[x], x >= xmin && x <= xmax}, x][[1]]
 (* -36.7965 *)

f2[x_] := (f[x (xmax - xmin)] - ymin)/(ymax - ymin)

Plot[f2[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To scale both the domain and the range to unit interval we can use `Rescale` as follows:

```
ClearAll[ySF, xSF, scaledF]
```

The function `xSF` rescales the horizontal range from  the interval `{0,1}` to the interval `{xmin, xmax}` and `ySF` rescales the vertical range to `{0,1}`:

```
xSF[xmin_, xmax_] := Rescale[#, {0, 1}, {xmin, xmax}] &;

ySF[f_, xmin_, xmax_] := Module[{yr = 
 Through[{NMinValue, NMaxValue}[{f[x], xmin <= x <= xmax}, x]]}, 
  Rescale[#, yr] &]
```

To define a rescaled version of `f` we compose `ySF`, `f` and `xSF`:

```
scaledF[f_, xmin_, xmax_] := ySF[f, xmin, xmax] @* f @* xSF[xmin, xmax]

Row[{Plot[100 Sin[x]/x, {x, -3 Pi, 10 Pi}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed["AllExpressions", Above]], 
  Plot[Evaluate[scaledF[Sin[#]/# &, -3 Pi, 10 Pi]@x], {x, 0, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed["AllExpressions", Above]]}]
```

[image]

Using Rom38's example:

```
Row[{Plot[Sqrt[x^3] Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed["AllExpressions", Above]], 
  Plot[Evaluate[scaledF[Sqrt[#^3] Sin[#] &, 0, 4 Pi]@x], {x, 0, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed["AllExpressions", Above]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misunderstanding the question.
Maybe write some `ScalingFunctions -> {{# &, # &}, {# &, #0 &}}` can work.

**Original**

One of this function is.

```
Plot[Sqrt[1 - (1 - x)^2], {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Or

```
sol = DSolve[{f''[t] == -t^2 , f[0] == 0, f[1] == 1}, f, t]
Plot[f[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Or some Bezier Curve

```
ParametricPlot[
 BSplineFunction[{{0, 0}, {0.1, 0.3}, {0.5, 0.8}, {1, 1}}][t], {t, 0,1}]
```